# How to disallow tab key to switch focus between edit control and button within dialog box?

Tags: mfc

I have dialog box having buttons and edit box.
When edit control have focus then if I press tab key it moves and focus the button.
I wanted tab key work in such a way that it will not switch focus instead it should work as tab input inside edit control i.e. input to edit box as keys.

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/editctrl/keyboard/article.php/c513/Allowing-the-TAB-key-in-Edit-Controls.htm

Comment: Have the edit control set the `DLGC_WANTTAB` flag in response to `WM_GETDLGCODE`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is fairly simple, and essentially consists of handling the [WM_GETDLGCODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-getdlgcode) message. This allows a control implementation to fine-tune keyboard handling (among other things).

In MFC this means:

- Derive a custom control class from [CEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class).
- Add the [ON_WM_GETDLGCODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/wm-message-handlers-f-k) message handler macro to the message map.
- Implement the [OnGetDlgCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#ongetdlgcode) member function, that adds the `DLGC_WANTTAB` flag to the return value.
- Subclass the dialog's control, e.g. using the [DDX_Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-exchange-routines#ddx_control) function.

Header file:

```cpp
class MyEdit : public CEdit {
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg UINT OnGetDlgCode();
};
```

Implementation file:

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyEdit, CEdit)
    ON_WM_GETDLGCODE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP

UINT MyEdit::OnGetDlgCode() {
    UINT value{ CEdit::OnGetDlgCore() };
    value |= DLGC_WANTTAB;
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Override the [PreTranslateMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kkbhxcs2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function in your dialog like this :

```
BOOL CTestThreadDlg::PreTranslateMessage( MSG* pMsg )
{
  if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && pMsg->wParam == VK_TAB)
  {
    CWnd* pFocusWnd = GetFocus( );

    if (pFocusWnd != NULL && pFocusWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_EDIT2)
    {
      CEdit *pEditCtrl = (CEdit *)pFocusWnd ;
      int start, end ;
      pEditCtrl->GetSel(start, end) ;
      CString str ;
      pEditCtrl->GetWindowText(str) ;
      str = str.Left(start) + _T("\t") + str.Mid(end) ;
      pEditCtrl->SetWindowText(str) ;
      pEditCtrl->SetSel(start + 1, start + 1) ;
    }

    return TRUE ;
  }

  return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg) ;
}
```

In this example we check if the focus is in the IDC_EDIT2 edit control. You probably have to adapt this to your situation.

Comment: You're trying way too hard. Just have the edit control respond `DLGC_WANTTAB` to say "Send tabs to me rather than using them for navigation." This also fixes the bug where your code inserts a tab even though the user hit Shift+Tab or Ctrl+Tab.

Comment: @Raymond Chen,Can you help me on the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479791/how-to-allow-tab-key-to-use-as-input-in-edit-control-on-dialog-box-instead-of-na

Comment: Don't create two questions for the same thing.

Comment: Did you try `DLGC_WANTALLKEYS`?