# How to make the Tab key input the Tab character to focused edit control instead of navigating among dialog controls?

Tags: mfc

The present posting is continuation of post [How to disallow tab key to switch focus between edit control and button within dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443702/how-to-disallow-tab-key-to-switch-focus-between-edit-control-and-button-within-d) because I Just thought I needed a separate posting for this.

I followed the comments on that post to make the Tab key input the Tab character inside its edit control:

I created `EditCode` class derived from `CEdit` and I overrode method:

```
 afx_msg UINT OnGetDlgCode()
 {
     UINT uiCode = CEdit::OnGetDlgCode();
     uiCode |= DLGC_WANTTAB;
     return uiCode;
 }
```

And I added the respective handler entry in the class' message map:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(EditCode, CEdit)
    ON_WM_GETDLGCODE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

I also added a variable of type `EditCode` to the dialog class, but I could not still manage to fix it.

I tried to override `WindowProc` as follows

```
LRESULT CEditCode:: WindowProc(
   UINT message,
   WPARAM wParam,
   LPARAM lParam 
)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    LRESULT lres;
    switch (message) {
    case WM_GETDLGCODE:
        lres = CEdit::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
        lres |= DLGC_WANTTAB;
        return lres;
    }
    return CEdit::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

But until now, I had no success.

**EDIT:**
I am now able to make the Tab key input the Tab character by returning

```
  (DLGC_WANTCHARS | DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTTAB | DLGC_WANTALLKEYS).
```

I wanted the Shift+Tab key combination to still work for navigation, hence I wrote:

```
if(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0 )
{
   return CEdit::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

It is working fine, but whenever  press Shift+Tab for navigation and come back to edit box, then the Tab key is not working as input; instead it as navigates among controls. I am confused.

Comment: Try to directly return "DLGC_WANTCHARS | DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTTAB | DLGC_WANTALLKEYS" instead of appending to the results of CEdit::WindowProc. I'm not 100% sure why your solution doesn't work but I could image the results you get from the default implementation contains (a) flag(s) that conflict(s) with DLGC_WANTTAB.

Comment: @no__seriously great it is working. But i wanted tab as input which is now working and shift tab for navigation. but shft+tab is also givving tab as input.

Comment: Then I would filter wParam for the virtual key VK_TAB and check if shift is pressed by using GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0, finally returning the desired flags except DLGC_WANTTAB.

Comment: @no__seriouslyyes it is working perfectly thank you :) but same thing i did for cntrl_tab(GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0) but still i am getting tab inside edit control. I wanted control+tab use for forward navigation(shift_tab use for backward navigation which is working fine)

Comment: @Raymond Please see the edit part in my question. I am facing this problem. Please help me on this

Comment: I think `DLGC_WANTTAB | DLGC_WANTALLKEYS` is enough for what you want.

Comment: I normally use `if(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000)` instead of your dubious comparison.  By the way, did you also try with `GetAsyncKeyState`?

Comment: This didn't work for me. In MFC windows and dialogs are called with PreTranslateMessage. This code calls 'IsDailogMessage' which eats the tab away.